# Confusion whilst reading the proof of uniqueness of Poisson Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I wanted to show uniqueness to $\nabla^2 \phi=f$ subject to mixed boundary conditions; I was considering the following:

$\nabla^2u=0$ in a closed domain $D$ subject to $\alpha u+\beta\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ on $\partial D.$ (To avoid confusion, this is the general mixed condition. $\alpha =1, \beta =0$ is the Dirichlet, $\alpha =0, \beta =1$ is the Neumann.) Then the focus is to show if $u\equiv 0.$

Then I was presented this proposition that I had some trouble with.

*Proposition:* If $\alpha \neq0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\geq0$ then we have unicity.

*Proof:* Consider div$(u\nabla u)$, by simple identity div$(u\nabla u)=|\nabla u|^2+u\nabla^2u.$ Integrate over domain $D$ on both side and use divergence theorem we arrive at $$\int_D |\nabla u|^2dA=\int_{\partial D} u\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}ds.$$

Note from the above that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=-\frac{\alpha u}{\beta}$ on the boundary and so by considering signs we deduce $|\nabla u|=0$ thus $u=const=0,$ as required.

*My confusion:*

- Where did we use $\alpha \neq 0?$ It seems to me that we used $\beta \neq 0$ instead?
- However, my suspect cannot be possibly right because if we have $\alpha=0, \beta=1$ this is just Neumann and I already knew this won't correspond to a unique solution.

Where did I go wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: in either case alpha or beta not zero you can deduce u is constant by replacing either u or the normal derivative in the integral by the expression in the boundary condition. But alpha not 0 is required to use the boundary condition to get u=c with c=0

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is very clear! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(just promoting comment to answer)

The answer to your question comes from looking carefully at the steps and seeing exactly what is used where, and why.
In either case $\alpha\neq 0$ or   $\beta\neq0$, you can use the boundary condition:
$$ \int_D |\nabla u|^2 dA = \int_{\partial D} u\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} ds\overset{*}=\begin{cases}-\int_{\partial D} \frac\alpha\beta u^2 ds &\beta \neq 0 \\ -\int_{\partial D} \frac\beta\alpha (\frac{\partial u}{\partial n})^2 ds &\alpha \neq 0 \end{cases}$$
(The step marked $*$ is where the boundary condition is used.)
Considering the sign of the expressions as you said will lead to $u\equiv c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$, and hence $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Therefore the boundary condition reads
$$ \alpha u = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega.$$
It is at this point that you need $\alpha\neq 0$ to conclude that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, and hence $u=c=0$ on $\Omega$.